# Lowering the index for the Riemann Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry

Wikipedia says the value of the lowered Riemann Tensor can be expressed as:
$$R_{nmab}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ni}\left(\partial_m\partial_ag_{nb}-\partial_m\partial_bg_{na}-\partial_n\partial_ag_{mb}+\partial_n\partial_bg_{ma}\right)+g_{ni}(\Gamma^n_{la}\Gamma^l_{mb}-\Gamma^n_{lb}\Gamma^l_{ma})$$
But if I take the value of the lowered Riemann Tensor:
$$R_{nmab}=g_{ni}R^n_{mab}=g_{ni}(\partial_a\Gamma^i_{mb}-\partial_b\Gamma^i_{ma}+\Gamma^i_{la}\Gamma^l_{mb}-\Gamma^i_{lb}\Gamma^l_{ma})$$
Substituting the formula for the Christoffel Symbol:
$$\Gamma^n_{ab}=g^{nm}\Gamma_{mab}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_ag_{mb}+\partial_bg_{na}-\partial_mg_{ab}\right)$$
Applying the product rule I obtain:
$$R_{nmab}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ni}(\partial_ag^{ij}\Gamma_{jmb}-\partial_bg^{ij}\Gamma_{jma})+\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_m\partial_ag_{nb}-\partial_m\partial_bg_{na}-\partial_n\partial_ag_{mb}+\partial_n\partial_bg_{ma}\right)+g_{ni}(\Gamma^n_{la}\Gamma^l_{mb}-\Gamma^n_{lb}\Gamma^l_{ma})$$
Where is my mistake?

Comment: We can't know unless you post your full process here. But it's already bad sign that your answer has an extra $i$ index floating around that isn't summed over.

Comment: By Einstein's summation convention your expression for the Riemann tensor is wrong. On the right, your first term contains an index $i$ that does not appear on the right and is not summed over by any expression.

Comment: Oops, that was a copying mistake.

Comment: I was half asleep when I wrote this originally. It's corrected and clarified

Comment: you ought to do $R_{nmab}=g_{ni}R^i{}_{mab}$